# how to display column in sharepoint 2010 list using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint. I am trying to create a list using C#.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
list.OnQuickLaunch = true;
list.Fields.Add("Col1", SPFieldType.Text, true);
list.Update();
```

The new field created "Col1", is not displaying in the list. However, I am able to view this field in the list setting. To make it visible, I have make display enable in the View (default view i.e., All Items).

My question is can I achieve it programmatically? I have searched in Stackoverflow and google but could not find the satisfactory answer.

TIA,

Idds.

Comment: do u want to show it in the sharepoint view ??

Comment: Yes, I want to do it programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a reference to the `SPView`, add the field to the `ViewFileds` collection and update.

```
//get a reference to the target view
SPView view = list.Views["Existing_View_Name"];

// add field to the view
view.ViewFields.Add("Col1");

// update view for the new field
view.Update();
```